# Ending batch file interaction to disable Python output redirection

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, windows-10

I am working on a Python project (personal, non-distribution) to modify filenames in Windows 10. I'm using a batch file as a target for drag-n-drop.

Batch file:

```
@echo off
    
python "C:\path\to\PythonProjects\GetFnDragDrop.py" %*
    
pause
```

GetFnDragDrop.py (demo script):

```
import sys
import os


class Video_Play(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def play(self):
        from os import startfile
        startfile(self.path)


def get_fn_drag_drop():
    file_paths = sys.argv[1:]

    return file_paths


file_paths = get_fn_drag_drop()

for fname in file_paths:
    file_directory = os.path.dirname(fname)
    file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fname))
    fname_new = file_directory + '\\' + file_name + ' -1-' + file_ext

    os.rename(fname, fname_new)
    movie = Video_Play(fname_new)
    movie.play()
```

The batch file starts GetFnDragDrop.py and the filenames are captured in the script as desired. At this point, I am finished with the batch file.

Is there any way to end interaction between the script and the batch file/command prompt **so that I can print and get error messages in the Python terminal in PyCharm instead of the CMD window?** While I am working on the script, it is annoying to have print statements and error messages appear in a separate CMD window instead of the terminal in PyCharm.

I tried removing the "pause" from the batch file as well as adding "exit" to it but the Python print statements and error messages were still directed to the CMD window.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using a batch file after all? I'm sure there is a way to get the items dragged-and-dropped onto a Python script…

Comment: `start "" python "C:\path\to\PythonProjects\GetFnDragDrop.py" %*`

Comment: I will try to update my question again to clarify what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks @Gerhard. Although it stopped the output from going to the CMD window, it still didn't send it to the terminal in PyCharm.

Comment: Let me guess, it just flashes a terminal window?

Comment: @Gerhard If I remove the "pause" statement in the batch file, the CMD terminal window flashes, otherwise it stays open. There is no effect on the PyCharm terminal.

Comment: It is not possible. did you debug your python script? Give it a manual file name and run it by itself using `start` to see where the script fails.